# Cucumber + EmailSpec + Rails3: why does it say no emails are sent when it actually works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I'm using [EmailSpec](https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec) to test emails with Cucumber. My tests fail and says no email is being sent, but **I couldn't find anything wrong with my code, so I tried it in production and emails are sent**.

Here's the failing step:

```
# ...
And I should see "You have requested for a condition report, and will be emailed one as soon as we are able to process your request." # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:107
And I should receive an email # features/step_definitions/email_steps.rb:51
  expected: 1,
       got: 0 (using ==) (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
  ./features/step_definitions/email_steps.rb:52:in `/^(?:I|they|"([^"]*?)") should receive (an|no|\d+) emails?$/'
  features/request_for_condition_reports.feature:18:in `And I should receive an email'
When I open the email                                                                                                                 # features/step_definitions/email_steps.rb:72
Then I should see "Ramon (ramon@email.com) wants a condition report for" in the email body
```

And here's the class that sends the email:

```
class ReportRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  private

  def notify_admin
    Mailer.condition_report_request_to_admin(self).deliver
  end
end
```

What should I do to fix this test?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that method is really call ?

Comment: I'm sure it's really called because the emailing works (I tried it on production, and I get an email when I do those steps), but the scenario fails.

Comment: If the below didn't work for you and if you're using example@example.com in your factory and feature, try changing that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I [wasn't the only one](https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec/issues#issue/15) that had this problem! You're supposed to change the default email set in email_steps.rb to the email that you expect to receive emails with.